# Restarting same Java Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

OK anyone please, I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66172534/running-same-thread-multiple-times-on-android) question as an Android question but I realized I was able to recreate similar scenario on a pure Java Application.

I created a Thread class as an inner class and override its **run()** method

```
    Thread aaa = new Thread(){
        public void run() {
            for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
                System.out.println(getId()+" <-"+i);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000 * 1);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
    };
```

In my Main method, I started that Thread and after that slept for 6 seconds (the idea the is that the Thread would have finished its run method by time **main** wakes up back) and I then attempt to start same thread again

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        //Start the thread
        test.aaa.start();
        

        try {
            Thread.sleep(6000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Start same dead thread again      
        test.aaa.start();
    }
```

On my Ubuntu machine starting the Thread again in that last line gives *IllegalThreadStateException* which was what I considered the norms. Output looks like:

```
9 <-0
9 <-1
9 <-2
9 <-3
9 <-4
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:708)
    at Test.main(Test.java:15)
```

But on My Android device its running same Thread over - over again,  Output looks like :

```
50023 <-0
50023 <-1
50023 <-2
50023 <-3
50023 <-4
50023 <-0
50023 <-1
50023 <-2
50023 <-3
50023 <-4
```

I don't understand how same Thread is started again, atleast the Id proves that.

Comment: You can't restart a Java `Thread`. See the Javadoc. You have to create a new one. Probably you should just create a `Runnable` instead of a `Thread` and create a new `Thread` around it every time you need to.

Comment: But there it is, my device is creating same thread again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the source of your confusion is because you are testing on two similar but not identical runtime environments. In other words, there are two different runtime environments or virtual machines (aka VM) at play here:

- the runtime environment of your computer or [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) which is usually based on [Oracle JDK](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html) or [OpenJDK](https://openjdk.java.net/);
- the runtime environment of your mobile device which is usually based on [Dalvik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_(software)) or [Android Runtime (ART)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Runtime) .

The behaviour you've described where the 2nd invocation of `thread.start()` led to an `IllegalThreadStateException` is the correct behaviour on a standard Java runtime environment based on the JVM.

The behaviour you're experiencing where the code doesn't crash on your device is because the Java runtime environment on your Android device is different --  it does not fully conform to the [JVM spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/index.html).

Comment: OK seems so because on other Android devices including the Android Emulator, I realize starting the Thread again causes crash. I was only able to recreate this on my own physical Android device.            OK so is it safe to say the Runtime environment on my Phone can't be relied upon right? Like something must be wrong in there

Comment: More like you should prepared to experience small differences in how your multi-threaded code will behave when testing on different runtime environments. The behaviour of your phone is closer to what your users will experience than the behaviour of your computer, so better to focus your testing of multi-threaded code on how your app behaves on phone runtime environments.

Comment: OK got that, thanks for the answer and the link

Answer (score 1):

As per Java specification, you can only start a thread once. In other words, you must not start a thread which has already been started.

The fact that it happens to work on Android (or anywhere else) is irrelevant. Even if it appears to work, it is still wrong and it can cause unpredictable results.

If you need to run a thread again, create a new one.

As an alternative, you can use an `ExecutorService`, but that's a different topic.

Comment: Yes I knew it could be irrelevant but it working in the first place is where the problem lies. Like it only happens on my personal Android device and not on other Android devices I have checked on

Comment: Like if not of recent that I now have a Computer, all I had all this while was this Android device and I base most of my knowledge on the Output of my program

Comment: Implementation of Java Virtual Machine is free to choose how the threads are handled in the background. This choice can change at any moment, and that's why you must not rely on it.